# How to check if a char in a parsed line is part of a string variable in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to implement in python a function that checks if the '#' symbol inside a parsed line is part of a string variable.

```
def comment_part_of_string(line,comment_idx):
    """
     :param line: stripped line that has '#' symbol
            comment_idx: index of '#' symbol in line
     :return: return True when the '#' symbol is inside a string variable
     """
```

for example, I want the function to return True for:

```
> line="peace'and#much'love"
> comment_idx=line.find('#')
```

and False for:

```
> line="peace#love"
> comment_idx=line.find('#')
```

How can I check if a char in a parsed line is part of a string variable?

**edit**
I tried this and it also worked:

```
def comment_part_of_string(line, comment_idx):
    """
     :param comment_idx: index of '#' symbol in line
     :param line: stripped line that has '#' symbol
     :return: return True when the '#' symbol is inside a string variable
     """
    if ((line[:comment_idx].count(b"\'") % 2 == 1 and line[comment_idx:].count(b"\'") % 2 == 1)
            or (line[:comment_idx].count(b"\"") % 2 == 1 and line[comment_idx:].count(b"\"") % 2 == 1)):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this output?

Comment: Is it the parsed line that is in python or is the program that is doing the checking that is in python? In which sense is "peace#love" a "parsed line"?

Comment: Yes I am trying to parse a code in python. parsed_line is a line parsed from a python code. for example: A="peace#love" and then line='A="peace#love" '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by checking the number of single quotes(`'`) before the `#` symbol. If it is even, that means it is outside a string literal and if its odd, then it is inside a string. Do it like so:

```
def comment_part_of_string(line, comment_idx):
    """
     :param line: stripped line that has '#' symbol
            comment_idx: index of '#' symbol in line
     :return: return True when the '#' symbol is inside a string variable
     """
    count = line.split(line[comment_idx])[0].count("'")
    if(count % 2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
def iscomment(line):
    line = line.split(" ")
    for i in line:
        if "#" in i:
            if '"' in i or "'" in i:
                return True
    return False
```

It splits line for spaces, then is goes through parts of line and if it find ' or " and # in line it returns True.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using regex.
Note: Strings can be inside ' or ". So have to consider that also.

```
import re
def comment_part_of_string(line):
    pattern=r'\'.*#.*\'|\".*#.*\"'
    if re.findall(pattern,line):
        return True
    return False
```

Output:

```
>>> comment_part_of_string("peace'and#much'love")
True
>>> comment_part_of_string("peace#love")
False
>>> comment_part_of_string('peace"and#much"love')
True
```